# I can't compile a Qt project

Tags: 14.04, compiling, qt, c++

I was trying to compile a project I checked out from github but I get these errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQtGui
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQtNetwork
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQtCore
```

It worked before but then I installed some application that pulled in Qt5 and nothing works anymore. How do I diagnose what's wrong or the reason why linker can't find these libraries.

Comment: If it worked previously with Qt4, have you tried setting the `QT_SELECT` environment variable before starting the build process e.g. `export QT_SELECT=qt4`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a Qt project, Qt Creator tool may be of use -- it supports multiple Qt versions to be set as build kits, you just need to have the proper compiler installed and locate the `qmake` file of the desired Qt.

If otherwise you are convinced to build something from command line (ex.: development is not the key goal), check the following:

```
qmake --version  # which qt
pkg-config --modversion QtCore #module version
```

And yes, `export QT_SELECT = <desired Qt version>` also works, when you need to switch versions for you build.

Comment: I did try qt creator and it gives me the same error.
Here's my output if that is of any help.
http://pastebin.com/aVXx6kzY

Comment: Hmm.  `QT += core gui network` in *.pro file ?
Or dirty hack: `LIBS+=-L"/usr/local/lib"` ?